# MYSQL WorkBench Not Connecting to Database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL workbench is not connecting to server in localhost.

But, I was able to connect using command line. Now access denied in workbench and command prompt.

tried re-install Mysql, its working first time. after system (computer) restart, its not working again.

Tried to connect using workbench 5.2.

what is wrong with my installation or do i need to do any thing in Mysql.

I am using windows 8.1

Comment: Why do you use such an ancient MySQL Workbench version? The current one is 6.2.3. Additionally, how did you install the MySQL Server? If not done with that use the MySQL Windows Installer, which gives you all needed parts (including latest server + workbench software). It will also install a Windows service for the server to have it automatically start on system boot time.

Comment: Upgrade to Workbench 6.2.3, as Mike said, and also consider installing "MySQL Notifier" to manage your MySQL connections (this can also be done via the aforementioned MySQL Windows Installer). Lastly, it sounds like you don't have the MySQL server installed as a service (meaning, it won't start/stop when Windows reboots).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works only if you are connecting to localhost.

Use 127.0.0.1 as you hostname or simply type in "localhost" and Mysql server port being 3306.
And 
Make sure there are no spaces after username. It might sometime cause you trouble.

Answer (score -1):

is the MySQL database *server* on? go to command line and (er..at least in unix) you do `/sbin/service mysqld start`, [in windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html) you do

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld"
```

I think the server stops every time you restart your computer unless you setup a bit. In UNIX, to start the mysqld server at boot time you have to copy `support-files/mysql.server` to the right place for your system. Not sure about Windows.

If that didn't help, try here?
https://superuser.com/questions/666521/how-do-i-start-a-mysql-server-in-windows